# How can I include translations in my managed package?

Tags: managed-package, aura, customlabel, namespace, translation-workbench

I want to include translations in my managed package so that all the text in my managed package matches the user's locale if I included a translation for that locale.

What I have done so far:

So far I have put a few custom labels on an aura component in my package as a test, then I enabled translation workbench (via `setup->user interface->translation workbench->translation language settings`) and added in a translation on a locale for one of my custom labels and switched the current locale to that language using `profilepic->settings->my personal information->language & time zone->language`

Everything translated like a charm!

While this is great, I wanted to make sure that I could reproduce on a new scratch org and pull it into my source code, so I did a `sfdx force:source:pull` and it appropriately updated my `CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml` file and gave me a new translation file: `fr.translation-meta.xml` (my test language was French)

I then tried to create a new scratch org with these changes to my code, but I got the following errors:

```
─────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  force-app/main/default/translations/fr.translation-meta.xml                      Not available for deploy for this organization
Error  force-app/main/default/aura/myWidget/myWidget.cmp                                Label my_label_name cannot be found in namespace c.
```

I don't know why I am getting the first error at all.

Here is what I am going to try for the second error: I am currently working with my sysadmins to connect the production namespace that my package uses to my devhub. After that is set up, I plan on setting the namespace in my `sfdx-project.json` file (see below) from blank to my production namespace. After I do that, I will change my label references from `{! $Label.c.my_label_name }` to `{! $Label.mynamespace.my_label_name }` instead.

Current `sfdx-project.json`, for reference:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [{
        "path": "force-app/main",
        "default": true
    }],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "46.0"
}
```

Am I approaching this correctly to include translations in my managed package? Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

(cross posted to https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Lightning&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9062I000000XumFQAS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to include translations in your managed package, you just need to specify them in the package manifest. This is the same process as adding a custom field, object, class, etc.

In order to deploy translations to a Scratch Org, the Translation Workbench must first be enabled. To do this, include the following settings in your org configuration file:

```
  "settings": {
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    }
  }
```

This file must be specified when creating a scratch org using the -f option, as in:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -a myscratchorg -f config/my-scratch-config.json -u devhuborg
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the 1st error and the second error (trying to reference the 'c' namespace) went away as well. I am still going to try to connect up the namespace so that I can fully test it as it will be in production, but you got me unblocked, thanks!

Comment: @RobertHyatt You're welcome!